Adding multiple DHCP scopes using CSV to define variables in Powershell
I work for a School District and we have 60 school sites.  I am attempting to bulk add DHCP scopes to each site using powershell so I don't have to click through the GUI for each scope.  I am needing to run the (3) following commands to add the scope and associated options but would like to capture data from a CSV to add the scope to all 60 sites:
Add-DhcpServerv4Scope -cn dhcp1 -Name "PAH IOT" -StartRange 10.123.112.2 -EndRange 10.123.119.254 -SubnetMask 255.255.248.0 -LeaseDuration 4.00:00:00;

Set-DhcpServerv4OptionValue -cn "dhcp1" -ScopeId 10.123.112.0 -DnsServer 10.2.10.95,10.2.10.96 -Router 10.123.112.1 -DnsDomain mydomain.net;

Add-DhcpServerv4FailoverScope -cn "dhcp1" -Name "dhcp1.mydomain.net-dhcpfailover1.mydomain.net" -ScopeId 10.123.112.0

This is literally my first attempt at Powershell, so don't mind my script...but it failed miserably.  I created a CSV with the following headers and attempted to reference them in the script as a variable.
Server,ScopeName,StartIP,EndIP,Mask,Lease,ScopeID,Router,DNS,Failover
dhcp1,PAHIOT,10.123.112.2,10.123.119.254,255.255.248.0,4.00:00:00,10.123.112.0,10.123.112.1,10.2.10.95,dhcp1.mydomain.net-dhcpfailover1.mydomain.net

$Scopes = import-csv "$env:OneDrive - \\desktop\\DHCP\\Scopes.csv"

Foreach ($Scope in $Scopes) {
Add-DhcpServerV4Scope -Computername $_.server -Name $_.ScopeName -StartRange $_.StartIP -EndRange $_.EndIP -SubnetMask $_.Mask -LeaseDuration $_.Lease
Set-DhcpServerV4OptionValue -ComputerName $_.Server -ScopeID $_.ScopeID -DNSServer $_.DNS -Router $_.Router -DnsDomain mydomain.net
Add-DhcpServerv4FailoverScope -CN $_.Server -Name $_.Failover -ScopeID $\_.ScopeID
}

What I am attempting to do is fill out the CSV with information for all 60 of my sites with the required information and run the script to have all the DHCP scopes with my required options set.  I was thinking that the $_. function would call to the associated header and use the value as the variable and process each line ($Scopes) through the end of the CSV.  Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks.

Change $_.Server -> $scope.Server, repeat for the remaining instances of $_.<property>

In general it is best practice to use single quotes to bracket strings, unless you need the functionality that double quotes provides.  Specifically, what does the dollar sign mean in front of ENV: That dollar sgin inside a double quotes string is gong to trigger an attempt to resolve the variable named ENV and I don't think that's what you want.

I second the comment from Mathias Jensen.  If you want to read up on the use of $_ you can reference the following online help.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.4

It's very easy to confuse foreach and foreach-object.  Be careful.

@WalterMitty s and n are two entirely different letters

Use the $Scope iterator variable you declared in the foreach statement:
$Scopes = Import-Csv "$env:OneDrive - \\desktop\\DHCP\\Scopes.csv"

foreach ($Scope in $Scopes) {
    Add-DhcpServerV4Scope -Computername $Scope.Server -Name $Scope.ScopeName -StartRange $Scope.StartIP -EndRange $Scope.EndIP -SubnetMask $Scope.Mask -LeaseDuration $Scope.Lease
    Set-DhcpServerV4OptionValue -ComputerName $Scope.Server -ScopeID $Scope.ScopeID -DNSServer $Scope.DNS -Router $Scope.Router -DnsDomain mydomain.net
    Add-DhcpServerv4FailoverScope -CN $Scope.Server -Name $Scope.Failover -ScopeID $Scope.ScopeID
}

